# Expected identifier, got 'LParen'

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, truffle-contract

I try using `IterableMapping` by this [example](https://github.com/szerintedmi/solidity-itMapsLib).
I have error when I compiling contract by truffle:

> Expected identifier, got 'LParen'

This is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

import "./itMapsLib.sol";

contract User
{
  using itMaps for itMaps.itMapUintAddress;

  itMaps.itMapAddressUint im_myAddressUintMap;

 function addOwner(address _key, uint value) returns (bool){
   im_myAddressUintMap.insert(_key, value);
   return true;
 }

  function allSum() returns (uint sum) 
  { 
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't seem to have defined `im_myUintUintMap` anywhere (unless it's somewhere else in code that isn't included in your snippet).

Comment: I define 'im_myAddressUintMap' as example of 'itMaps.itMapAddressUint', but I don`t undestand  why is it not work.

Comment: You are trying to insert a key/value pair into a variable called `im_myUintUintMap`. That variable does't exist. You need to change `im_myUintUintMap.insert()` to `im_myAddressUintMap.insert()`.

Comment: (Either that, or declare the correct variable: `itMaps.itMapUintUint im_myUintUintMap;`)

Comment: Ok, thanks I correct my mistake, but problem don`t resolve.

Comment: Okay, the next thing: what is `_key` and `value`? You are passing them to `insert()`, but they don't exist.

Comment: key it is address of owner example 0xC0222fBf1773A5e157e4d25Bf634E99C73C0637F , value this is amount of something(tokens or either). I rewrite my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is several problems with your code.

You copy paste the function prototype instead of calling it you should use
`im_myAddressUintMap.insert( key, value);`

And you have to make this insert inside a function or inside the constructor ( function with the name of the contract )

```
function insert( address key, uint value ) public {
    im_myAddressUintMap.insert( key, value );
}
```

so the contract should be something like this

second import is to test on [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

import "./itMapsLib.sol";  
//import "https://github.com/szerintedmi/solidity-itMapsLib/itMapsLib.sol";    

contract User
{
  using itMaps for itMaps.itMapAddressUint;

  itMaps.itMapAddressUint im_myAddressUintMap;

  function insert ( address key, uint value) public {
    im_myAddressUintMap.insert( key, value);
  }
}
```

Edit : you edited your contract. The last error you have is the incorrect import of `using itMaps for itMaps.itMapUintAddress;` you're using `itMapAddressUint`